# Vuex state is updated by action but the computed property is not responding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to fetch some data from firebase. I have the a `store.js`, and imported in to the `main.js`. So the problem is, the data is not correctly printed out when the page is loaded. However, the console.log in mutations shows that the data is fetched correctly as it should. I guess the problem is that, the action is able to fetch the data and update the state, however, the page is rendered before the computed property is changed? Another thing I noticed is, whenever I edit something and save in vscode, the content suddenly shows up, but it goes away if I refresh the page. I think this also means that the data indeed is fetched, but just not showed up.  Wondering if anyone can help. Really appreciate it.

```
// store.js

mport Vue from 'Vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import globalAxios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    dietRecords: {
      breakfest: {},
      lunch: {},
      dinner: {},
      snacks: {}
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setDietRecords (state, data) {
      state.dietRecords = data
      console.log(state.dietRecords) // this print out correct data
    }
  },
actions: {
    fetchData ({commit, state}) {
      globalAxios.get('my_data.json')
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        const resultArray = {
          breakfest: {},
          lunch: {},
          dinner: {},
          snacks: {}
        };
        for (let key in data) {
          resultArray[data[key].meal_type][key] = data[key]
        };
        commit('setDietRecords', resultArray)
      })
    }
  },
  getters: {
    dietRecords (state) {
      return state.dietRecords
    }
  }
})

//myapp.vue
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import EditRecord from "./editRecord.vue"

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      addRecord: {
        breakfest: false,
        lunch: false,
        dinner: false,
        snacks: false
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    diet () {
        return this.$store.getters.dietRecords
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchDietRecords')
      console.log(this.diet)
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchDietRecords')
  }
}
```

Comment: Computed properties return current data despite the life-cycle hook of the component. If the there's any change in data after page is rendered, computed properties get updated. 
Can you share your template code as well for me to have a better look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it has been a while, but I actually figured it out on my own. So the reason is I should import Vue from 'vue' not 'Vue'. It's such a small error after a lot of work. Hope this maybe helpful for other people... Check your package name first!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're calling  fetchDietRecords action but it's name is fetchData.
Second of all, your fetchData method is async, meaning that it may take 1 second to make the axios call but the console.log is called immidiately. The solution is to return the promise from the axios call and call then on the returned promise or use async await.

```
return globalAxios.get('my_data.json') // in your action
```

First one:

```
this.$store.dispatch('fetchDietRecords').then(() => {
    console.log(this.diet)
})
```

Second one:

```
created() {
    this.foo()
},
methods: {
   async foo() {
     await this.$store.dispatch('fetchDietRecords')
     console.log(this.diet)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps